# How to do a sign a smartcontract transaction from angular

Tags: angular, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to do a sign transaction from the Angular application.

I am using this **ethers** package to initialize the instance of the smart contract. Here I want to sign for the function --- method1(**string, unit256, unit256**).

```
  import abi from "ethereumjs-abi";
  import {toBuffer} from "ethereumjs-util";
  import { ethers } from 'ethers';

    
  instance = new ethers.Contract(ADDRESS, ABI, provider.getSigner());
  functionSignature = await instance.method1("abc",123,456).encodedABI(); //Here it fails, saying encodedABI is not a function. But same line works fine on nodejs.
  let messageToSign = this.constructTransactionMessage(nonce, chainId, functionSignature, contractAddress);
  let hex = "0x" + messageToSign.toString("hex");
  let signature = await provider.signTransaction(hex); // I don't know is it right or not.
  console.log(signature); //Final step


  async constructTransactionMessage(nonce, chainId, functionSignature, contractAddress) {
   return abi.soliditySHA3(
      ["uint256","address","uint256","bytes"],
      [nonce, contractAddress, chainId, toBuffer(functionSignature)]
   );
  }
```

I am getting the error at `functionSignature`, saying

> encodedABI is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`utils.Interface`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/) in ethers v5 to encode function calldata:

```
const encoder = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI)
const encodedData = encoder.encodeFunctionData('method1', [
  'abc',
  123,
  456,
])
```

Also in your code `signTrnsaction` looks like it has a typo.

Comment: Its saying encodeFunctionCall is not a function

Comment: are you using ethers v4 or v5?

Comment: version is @5.0.24

Comment: sorry there was a mistake, it should be `encodeFunctionData` not `encodeFunctionCall` [source](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/8e3cfd8517d69f9c6517e8141191b697bb4a645b/packages/abi/src.ts/interface.ts#L290)

Comment: for signing use the sign transaction method on the ethers wallet or signer, eg.  `signer.signTransaction({to: '0x123...', data: encodedData, value: '0x0'})` https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signTransaction